# passing HTTP GET values in url

Tags: android, http-get, android-internet

i'm trying to send HTTP GET Request with values passed in URL for the site

http://somenthing.com/c/chk.php?val=somevalue

I used the following code but it doesn't seems to work

```
HttpResponse response = null;
try {        
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("http://somenthing.com/c/chk.php?val=somevalue"));
    response = client.execute(request);
    } 
    catch (URISyntaxException e) 
    {        
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return;
```

i'm not getting any error, the above code works when the button is pressed and I have used the permission.

Upon receiving the HTTP GET Request the back end process is done by server.

Comment: what's the problem, again?

Comment: post your whole logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
// ---Connects using HTTP GET---
        public static InputStream OpenHttpGETConnection(String url) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return inputStream;
        }
```